# Are there ways to intercept web requests on the web server layer??.

Tags: web-server

I have a vm protected by siteminder provided by ca technologies with their agent residing on the web server. I want to intercept http requests before they are intercepted by the agent provided by siteminder. The main reason is I want to use the content-type header to differentiate between soap requests from other web requests with content type as text/html. Can anyone suggest some ways?

Comment: This is more of a product support question than a security question. I've flagged a mod to look at migration options, since there are other sites that would be better suited.

Comment: it is also important to tell us which web server you are using because SiteMinder (and the other filtering session managers) have different approaches to intercepting HTTP requests for different web server products (apache httpd, IIS etc)

Comment: we are using apache here